# Change spinner background

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created a spinner which looks like

[image: spinner]

My layout file is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        android:padding="7dip" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/select_city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:prompt="@string/selectCity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:text="@string/City"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

What I want is to make the background of the spinner transparent but still show the downward arrow. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create xml file and place it in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_pressed" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
</selector>
```

.

```
<Spinner ..... android:background="@drawable/selector_slim_spinner" ..... />
```

For more Information Check this [Change Spinner Style In Android](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/06/25/change-spinner-style-in-android/)

Comment: but the greyish gradient will still be there!

Comment: those are 9-patch images, if you want to use your custom images you can use them in your design

Comment: i got this but i cant set text to the `Spinner` because the background is overlaying my text

Answer (score 0):

You should create a slector and give that selector as background to your spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/..." />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/..." />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this resource [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate android components like Android 4.0