# How to change transparency of a custom dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

**xml for the dialog:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/redeemFailedTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="SORRY,\nYOU HAVE INSUFFICIENT\n POINTS FOR THIS\n REDEMPTION." 
    android:gravity="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialogCrossImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redeemFailedTextView"
    android:src="@drawable/dialog_ic_close_focused_holo_light" />
```

**java code for the dialog:**

```
final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(getActivity());
                    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_redeem_failed);

                    dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

                    dialog.show();

                    ImageView dialogCrossImageView=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogCrossImageView);
                    dialogCrossImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

**Rendered dialog:**

[image]

Why the background of the dialog is black ? How can I make it more transparent ? How to change the background color maintaing transparency ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can try the following:**

```
ColorDrawable dialogColor = new ColorDrawable( Color.BLACK);
dialogColor.setAlpha(150); //(0-255) 0 means fully transparent, and 255 means fully opaque
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(dialogColor)
```

Comment: can you please answer me this question as well ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220758/weird-spinner-behaviour